# Nested fragments and custom presenter

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm struggling with nested fragments.  I have an activity that uses a drawer to swap out the main content for another fragment.  Some of these second fragments are master-detail views where the detail view takes a DetailsViewModel.

```
public class CustomPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter, ICustomPresenter
{
    // map between view-model and fragment host which creates and shows the view based on the view-model type
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IFragmentHost> _dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IFragmentHost>();

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        IFragmentHost host;
        if (this.TryGetHost(request.ViewModelType, out host))
        {
            if (host.Show(request))
                return;
        }
        base.Show(request);
    }

    public override void Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        IFragmentHost host;
        if (this.TryGetHost(viewModel.GetType(), out host))
        {
            host.Close(viewModel);
            return;
        }

        base.Close(viewModel);
    }

    public void Register(Type viewModelType, IFragmentHost host)
    {
        this._dictionary[viewModelType] = host;
    }

    private bool TryGetHost(Type viewModelType, out IFragmentHost host)
    {
        if (this._dictionary.TryGetValue(viewModelType, out host))
            return true;

        host = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my activity:

```
    private void RegisterNavigationViewModels()
    {
        var presenter = Mvx.GetSingleton<ICustomPresenter>();

        presenter.Register(typeof(MapFragViewModel), this);
        presenter.Register(typeof(PersonnelViewModel), this);
    }

    public bool Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        // Handle drawer navigation

        try
        {
            Fragment contentFragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.content_frame);

            MvxFragment fragment;
            var section = this.OperationsViewModel.GetSectionForViewModel(request.ViewModelType);

            switch (section)
            {
                case OperationsViewModel.Section.Map:
                    if (contentFragment is MapFragment)
                        return true;

                    fragment = new MapFragment();
                    break;
                case OperationsViewModel.Section.Personnel:
                    if (contentFragment is OperationalPersonnel)
                        return true;

                    fragment = new OperationalPersonnel();
                    break;
                default:
                    Mvx.TaggedError("Operations Show", "Invalid Show request for {0}", request.ViewModelType.ToString());
                    return false;
            }

            var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
            var viewModel = loaderService.LoadViewModel(request, null /* saved state */);

            fragment.ViewModel = viewModel;

            // HACK
            if (section == OperationsViewModel.Section.Map)
                fragment.ViewModel = this.OperationsViewModel.MapFragViewModel;

            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment/*, fragmentView.GetType().ToString()*/).Commit();
            this._drawerList.SetItemChecked(this.OperationsViewModel.NavigationItems.FindIndex(m => m.Id == (int)section), true);

            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            this._drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(this._drawerList);
        }
    }
```

As you can see Show() handles the navigation window.  I was thinking there may be a way in the child fragment OperationalPersonnel to register with the parent activity and presenter in OnAttach and unregister in OnDetach and somehow control the mapping there?  But then I still don't know what to do with Show()... maybe delegate control to the child fragment?  Alternatively I guess I could handle every possible grand-child fragment in Show but that seems leaky to me.

Comment: There is an example available which should be able to take care of situations like you describe. You can find it here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples